# How is the Test Code coverage required for deploying calculated?

Tags: unit-test, failing-tests, deployment

Would like to Know- suppose we've sandbox from which we deploy to production. There is already set (A) of classes, some of whose test classes are failing 
Now we want to deploy Different set(B) of classes  to production from this Sandbox. 
All test classes related to set(B)  are working properly with test coverage > 75

Would I able to deploy set B through change set or any other means?.(Same sandbox has Set A also) 
Is it necessary to do 'Run all Tests' before deploying into production ?

Comment: Its important to recognize that a test class can pass in a sandbox, yet fail in a production environment for a large variety of reasons. And yes, you'll want to "run all tests" to make certain everything is working together. You can also disable any classes in the Sandbox that you don't intend to deploy before you run all tests. You don't want to waste your time trying to deploy what won't pass in a sandbox.

Answer (score 5):

Salesforce expects and requires 75% test code coverage on the combination of existing tests in your production environment AND the apex and tests you're trying to deploy. See the [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dev_lifecycle/Content/deploy.htm) for more information.

Important to know is also that [no test can fail](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_deploy_running_tests.htm), if this is the case your deployment will be rolled back.